# Error sum in sql request

Tags: django, postgresql

I have model:

```
class Sales(ModelWithCreator, models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    merchandise = models.ForeignKey(Merchandise)
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    debt = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    cost = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I have to get sum of all objects that model.
I tried that:

```
Sales.objects.all().extra(select={
            'total': 'Sum(price * count - cost)'
        })
```

But, I got error:

> column "sales_sales.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: SELECT (Sum(price * count - cost)) AS "total", "sales_sales"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to use the `.aggregate()` function. See [the Django documentation for *Aggregation*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/).

Something like this (though I haven't tested it):

```
Sales.objects.all().aggregate( total = Sum((F(price)*F(count)) - F(cost)) )
```

Also, that same documentation suggests using the `.query()` function to see what the resulting query is. That might help you see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sales.objects.all().extra(select={
            'total': 'Sum(price * count - cost)'
        }).values("total")
```

Comment: Got error too: column "sales_sales.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ... AND "sales_sales"."merchandise_id" = 1) ORDER BY "sales_sal...

Comment: Are you trying the above query itself or adding some filter ?

Comment: I used filter. E.g: sales = Sales.objects.filter(merchandise=some_merch). If try without filter query works.

Comment: In filter i used order_by. If don't use 'order_by' query works.

Comment: Why dont you post the exact query what you are trying?